# Eclipse CDT: Skip make/build before Debug/Run

Tags: eclipse, debugging, makefile, eclipse-cdt, skip

I am debugging a large Makefile-based C project which takes 15 seconds to run "make" even if no changes to the sources are done. That means that whenever I relaunch the program, I need to wait for 15 seconds before I can even start debugging.

The project was imported through "Import as existing project with Makefile" and I am using gdb for debugger.

I want that when I relaunch, it runs the executable which was build last. How to disable this extra step of building (i.e. running "make") before each launch/debug?

(In the rare case of actually changing the source, I am willing to do a manual build / make)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the main tab of the debug configuration there is a radio button "Disable auto build"

Comment: This answer is old and do not valid anymore.
Geniuses disabled this in new Eclipse versions, to help you....

Answer (score 21):

***Project - Disable Autobuild*** option does not always means autobuild is off. For example "Makegood" test automation plugin will trigger autobuild when ***Preferences - Run/Debug - launching - (General opt) Build before launch*** is ON. So turn it off if manual build needed.

Answer (score 5):

In current Eclipse builds like Oxygen.3 the option to disable automatic builds has been moved to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching, and here "Build (if required) before launching" under the General Options. There doesn't seem to be a differentiation anymore between doing this for debug only, appears to apply to both regular and debug runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the compile step if the project hasn't been modified but still want eclipse to compile it otherwise:

Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > "Build configurations only when there are Eclipse resource changes..."